# Trim images (Crop to remove all blank areas)

Tags: vb.net, image, crop

To reduce the size of some images I have, I'd like to remove the white padding that some have. The idea would be that if one has large white areas on the borders, then those can be cropped to save some space.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the cropping borders using

```
    Dim MinX As Integer = W : Dim MaxX As Integer = 0
    Dim MinY As Integer = H : Dim MaxY As Integer = 0

    Dim White As Integer = Color.White.ToArgb()
    For x As Integer = 0 To W - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To H - 1
            If Not Output.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() = White Then
                MinX = Math.Min(MinX, x)
                MaxX = Math.Max(MaxX, x)
                MinY = Math.Min(MinY, y)
                MaxY = Math.Max(MaxY, y)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```